# Magento 1: How to check if "Estimate Shipping" button is clicked or submitted?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, estimate

How can I check if Estimate Shipping form is submitted?

I could have check it like this:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit_name'])) ?>
```

But in the code it's a button type:

```
<button type="button" name="estimate" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Get a Quote')) ?>" onclick="coShippingMethodForm.submit()" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Get a Quote') ?></span></span></button>
```

With the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var coShippingMethodForm = new VarienForm('shipping-zip-form');
        var countriesWithOptionalZip = <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getCountriesWithOptionalZip(true) ?>;

        coShippingMethodForm.submit = function () {
            var country = $F('country');
            var optionalZip = false;

            for (i=0; i < countriesWithOptionalZip.length; i++) {
                if (countriesWithOptionalZip[i] == country) {
                    optionalZip = true;
                }
            }
            if (optionalZip) {
                $('postcode').removeClassName('required-entry');
            }
            else {
                $('postcode').addClassName('required-entry');
            }
            return VarienForm.prototype.submit.bind(coShippingMethodForm)();
        }
    //]]>
    </script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a two step process:

- button with name = estimate is clicked first
- clicking the button triggers the form with id = shipping-zip-form to be submitted

Comment: Thanks Raphael. I just added that name = "estimate" but how would I check it using PHP like: <?php if(isset($_POST['submit_name'])) ?> . Any idea?

Comment: @nhinzky well I reckon as long as the code in the `estimatePostAction` method is called that means the form has been submitted right ?

Comment: I would like to check it in template file .phtml like in cart.phtml. I tried it using that code above to check but it's not working.